# How to prove a map is epic using generalized elements only?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, yoneda-lemma, representable-functor, epimorphisms

I have a map $\require{AMScd}f\colon X \to Y$ in some category $\mathcal E$ which I would like to show is epic.  However the only description I have of $X$, $Y$, and $f$ is through the Yoneda embedding, in that I have an explicit description only of the functors $X_\ast,Y_\ast \colon \mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$ and of the natural transformation $f_\ast \colon X_\ast \to Y_\ast$.  (I am writing $Z_\ast = \hom({-},Z)$.)

Had I to show $f$ monic I would be happy since that can be formulated through limits, which the Yoneda embedding preserves.  Unfortunately I am sad as it does not preserve colimits.

In my particular case $\mathcal E$ is a topos; I have been shown one way in this context: $f$ is epic iff every generalized element $q\colon V \to Y$ is covered via $f$ by an element $p\colon U \to X$, in that there is an epi $u\colon U \twoheadrightarrow V$ such that the square commutes:
\begin{CD}
U @>u>>  V      \\\\
@VpVV    @VVqV \\\\
X @>>f> Y .
\end{CD}
Through Yoneda this translates to: For every $q \in Y_\ast V$ there are $p \in X_\ast U$ and $u\colon U \twoheadrightarrow V$ such that $f_\ast(p) = qu \in Y_\ast U$.

This is good, but I have no concrete description *in the category $\mathcal E$* of the arrow $q\colon V\to Y$, so it is hard to determine its composite with $u\colon U\to V$ which must be epic *in $\mathcal E$*.

Are there any other ways to prove $f$ epic using $f_\ast$?

Comment: I believe this is not possible in general. If your category were a _sheaf_ topos _and_ you have a site of definition then there is a concrete description.

Comment: In a topos a morphism is epi iff it is a cover iff it is orthogonal to the class monomorphisms of the topos. Can you use one of those descriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a small correction: note that if $X$ is an object of $\mathcal{C}$, then $\operatorname{Hom}({-}, X)$ is actually a *contravariant* functor $\mathcal{C}^{\operatorname{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Now, recall that this functor $\operatorname{Hom}({-}, X)$ acts on morphisms $\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}(U, V)$ precisely by sending $x \in \operatorname{Hom}(V, X) \mapsto x \circ \varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}(U, X)$.  Therefore, in terms of the functors $X_*$ and $Y_*$, the condition you want is precisely that for every object $U$ and element $y \in Y_*(U)$, there exists an epic morphism $\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}(V, U)$ and an element $x \in X_*(V)$ such that
$$Y_*(\varphi)(y) = f_*(x).$$

Comment: You are right about the contravariance of course. In any case this is exactly what I needed (and what I should have thought of), since I know $Y_\ast(\varphi)$. Thanks!